# `polkadot benchmark machine` does not pass (official documentation recommended configuration)

Tags: validator, benchmark

official configuration: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-validate-polkadot#requirements

We opened the appropriate server on aws according to the requirements in the official documentation.

[image]

But when I did benchmark(`polkadot` & `kusama`) on the new machine , only memery met the requirements, all other metrics failed.

this is my benchmark log:

[image]

Comment: Ah right, we did not update the specs file yet. Thanks for the hint! https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13308

Comment: So, what is the configuration now?

Answer (score 0):

The specs in the CLI were updated to be in accordance with the Wiki recommendations in [substrate#13317](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13317).

Judging by your posted pictures; The CPU stats look good and would all pass. The disk stats do not meet the recommendation though. You can find the table with the old and new stats in the MR linked above.